# Script to move folders and files with minage

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, robocopy

I'm using robocopy to delete folders/files from a directory.

The script:

```
  SET source1=c:\source
  SET destination=F:\destination
  SET switch1=/r:10 /w:1 /e /create /minage:10 /mt /LOG:F:\logs\backup.log

  FOR /d %%i IN ("%source1%\*") DO ROBOCOPY "%%i" "%destination%\%%~nxi" %switch1%
  FOR /d %%p IN ("%source1%\*") DO RMDIR "%%p" /s /q
  FOR /d %%q IN ("%destination%\*") DO RMDIR "%%q" /s /q
```

Source directory looks like this:

c:\source\directory\file1.txt (12 days old)

c:\source\directory2\file2.txt (5 days old)

My problem is this line in the script:

```
FOR /d %%p IN ("%source1%\*") DO RMDIR "%%p" /s /q
```

That line is not just RMDIR the directory's that were copied from source, its removing them all.  And a note, I cannot use /move as it will delete the source directory.  If I use /mov it won't delete all the subdirectories.

Any thoughts what I have wrong here?  Thanks in advance.

EDIT:  I am including the source directory dir /tw /s information for troubleshooting.  The ABT folder is the folder that should be deleted.

```
 Directory of C:\

09/27/2016  03:08 PM    <DIR>    .
09/27/2016  12:10 PM    <DIR>    ..
09/27/2016  03:09 PM    <DIR>    New Folder
06/25/2014  05:47 AM    <DIR>    abt
               0 File(s)

 Directory of C:\New folder

09/27/2016  03:09 PM    <DIR>
09/27/2016  03:08 PM    <DIR>
09/27/2016  03:09 PM
               1 File(s)

 Directory of C:\abt

06/25/2014  05:47 AM    <DIR>
09/27/2016  03:08 PM    <DIR>
03/20/2014  10:08 AM
06/25/2014  05:47 AM
04/28/2014  02:33 PM
05/20/2014  10:47 AM    <DIR>
02/18/2014  07:24 PM
05/20/2014  10:51 AM
               5 File(s)

 Directory of C:\abt\Scripts

05/20/2014  10:47 AM    <DIR>
06/25/2014  05:47 AM    <DIR>
10/02/2012  11:18 AM
02/02/2012  12:16 PM
02/17/2012  11:32 AM
```

Comment: Of course `rmdir /S` deletes all, that is what it is for; you could add the `/MOVE` option to `robocopy` so it *moves* matching files and directories to the destination, then you could omit the whole `for /D %%p` command line...

Comment: /move will delete the parent directory(source directory).  I need to be able to keep that.  So it would remove 'c:\source'.  Also, if I used /mov then that would not delete the subdirectory's under 'c:\source'.

Comment: You could use forfiles to do the age testing and then write whatever command you need. `forfiles /D -10 /C "cmd /c if @isdir==TRUE echo copying @relPath"`

Comment: @FloatingKiwi I was really hoping that would work.  I tried this and get an error(The syntax of the command is incorrect.).  `FORFILES /P C:\source /M *.* /D -10 /C "CMD /C RMDIR /s /q"`

Comment: @FloatingKiwi :  Also when I try this command I get the error(No files found with the specified search criteria), yet there are older directories and files than 10 days.  `FORFILES /P C:\source /M *.* /D -10 /C "CMD /C RMDIR /s /q @path"`

Comment: The dates being used are the last modified dates, not the creation date. That may be the issue you are seeing. If you post the output of `dir /TW /S c:\source` we might be able to help more

Comment: When you say you don't want to remove the source directory, are you talking about the folder itself or about the files inside it?

Comment: @FloatingKiwi, I have edited the original post with the results.

Comment: @MCND, source directory needs to stay, the source directory itself, the folders and files within that source directory I want deleted.  robocopy /move would be enough by itself if it didn't delete the source directory...

Comment: Hm... `/MOVE` can and will delete the source directory only in case *all* sub-items matched all the filters...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `robocopy` can handle everything except folder removal, the only thing you need to do is ensure `robocopy` will not be able to delete the folder.

This can be done simply by setting the source folder as the current active directory. You can not remove a folder that is in use.

```dos
SET "source1=c:\source"
SET "destination=F:\destination"
SET "switch1=/move /e /create /minage:10 /r:10 /w:1 /LOG+:F:\logs\backup.log"

pushd "%source1%" && (
    robocopy . "%destination%" %switch1%
    popd
)
```

The only drawback is that `robocopy` will show an error saying it can not delete the source folder because it is in use.

Comment: this one was cool to mess with.  However when I run the batch this way, the c:\source1\abt folder had a date of older than 10 days to start, I watched that date change after the batch runs to the current date.  There is a "scripts" folder under the "abt" folder as well, it too used to have a date older than 10 days and that date also changes to current date after batch run.  So what happens is all the files from under that "abt" folder move to the destination leaving behind both "c:\source1\abt" AND "c:\source1\abt\scripts".  But the folder "c:\source1\New Folder" doesn't move or change.

Comment: Basically, its the exact same thing that happens when I run it originally without setting source1 as current active directory and I use the /mov command.

Comment: I don't know if this matters, but C: is actually a network share.  I masked it with C:\ for public web purposes.

Comment: The error message you mention in your answer can be avoided by `2> nul`...

Comment: @TomWildt, The date change in the folder is the usual behaviour (folder date reflects the last change inside the folder). But if the folder is not removed then 1.- Maybe the `/mt` interfers itself (no, i don't think so, but ...) 2.- Not all files are removed because they not match the selection switches, so folders are not empty and they are not removed. For the first option, try removing the `/mt` switch. The second case can not be solved with `robocopy` and your best option is to include a `rmdir . /s /q` between the `robocopy` and `popd` lines.

Comment: @aschipfl, thank you, but no. `robocopy` outputs its operation errors to `stdout` (and/or the log file).

Comment: @TomWildt, sorry, I forget that you only want to remove the folders involved in the copy. Please, forget the `rmdir` option.

Comment: Sorry, you are right, I did not test it... so the (language-dependent) message could be filtered out by `find /V`, in case the `/LOG` option is replaced by redirection `>`...

Comment: That was it.  The multithread switch(/mt) was causing the issue...  Any idea why that is?  Running this on Windows Server 2k8 R2.

Comment: @TomWildt, whithout debugging `robocopy` I have to bet there is one thread trying to remove the folder while another one still holds a reference inside it.